# OpenGL/GLUT functions deprecated in mac os x

Tags: opengl, cmake, glut, clion, freeglut

I am currently a student and my coursework for one of my modules is about graphics programming. We have been given the framework for it and each week learning a new concept and implementing it.

This all works fine when working on the lab computers however i'm trying to do work from my macbook and it is given me a whole lotta warnings/errors.

I've looked online to find out how to link directories using cmake and I THINK i've got this part correct.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(GraphicsProgramming_Lab3)

CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.8")

IF(APPLE)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ( /System/Library/Frameworks )
    FIND_LIBRARY(GLUT_LIBRARY GLUT )
    FIND_LIBRARY(OpenGL_LIBRARY OpenGL )
    MARK_AS_ADVANCED (
            GLUT_LIBRARY
            OpenGL_LIBRARY)
    SET(EXTRA_LIBS ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OpenGL_LIBRARY})
ENDIF (APPLE)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Scene.cpp Scene.h Input.cpp Input.h Vector3.cpp Vector3.h)
add_executable(GraphicsProgramming_Lab3 ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(GraphicsProgramming_Lab3 ${GLUT_LIBRARY})
```

However when I look through my code I can see alot of the functions have a line scored through them and when I highlight them it's telling me they have deprecated.

Compiler giving me this message when trying to build:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: 
/Users/leekellie/CLionProjects/GraphicsProgramming_Lab3/cmake-build-debug
[ 40%] Building CXX object 
CMakeFiles/GraphicsProgramming_Lab3.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object 
CMakeFiles/GraphicsProgramming_Lab3.dir/Scene.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object 
CMakeFiles/GraphicsProgramming_Lab3.dir/Input.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object 
CMakeFiles/GraphicsProgramming_Lab3.dir/Vector3.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable GraphicsProgramming_Lab3
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum 
deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

and a bunch of other messages regarding the functions i'm using, here is one, they are all very similar:

```
"_glBegin", referenced from:
  Scene::render() in Scene.cpp.o
  Scene::render() in Input.cpp.o
"_glClear", referenced from:
  Scene::render() in Scene.cpp.o
  Scene::render() in Input.cpp.o
"_glClearColor", referenced from:
  Scene::Scene(Input*) in Scene.cpp.o
  Scene::Scene(Input*) in Input.cpp.o
```

Not really sure what I can do about this (first time ive ever used openGL & GLUT and first time using a mac to do my coursework on).

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does the `GLUT_LIBRARY` CMake variable *include* the OpenGL library? It doesn't look like that. Perhaps you should add `${OpenGL_LIBRARY}` as a target link library? Or use `${EXTRA_LIBS}`?

Comment: I feel like an idiot, thanks a lot you have no idea how much I appreciate it.